# Avoiding double render error when rendering a 500 screen from original render exception

Tags: exception, ruby-on-rails-2

In my Application controller, I have this to catch all otherwise uncaught exceptions...

```
 if Rails.env != "test"
     rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500
 end
```

It nicely catches exceptions and calls my "render_500" action, which logs the exception to the database and then renders a custom 500 page that includes a reference GUID for the exception (so I can look up details later).

The problem I'm running into is that if the exception caught occurred while rendering a page (e.g., bad code in a view, undefined variable referenced in a view), I end up triggering a second exception because of a double render error.

Thoughts on how to avoid this double render error on rendering the 500 page?

Answer (score 2):

The way to avoid a double render error by rendering a second time seems to be to check if there already exists a `response body`...

```
render unless response_body
```

Since, if I understand correctly you want the second render to replace the first you might try  replacing the existing `response_body` with your own.  Since `response_body` is an array of strings you could probably use [render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) then replace the response body like:

```
def render_500
   ...stuff...
   response = render_to_string "myController/view"
   status = 500
   unless response_body
     render :inline=> response
   else
     response_body = [response]
   end
end
```

Plus whatever other headers you needed to adjust.  This isn't tested and feels a bit unpleasant but I think it should work.  I'd be happy to hear if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a try and see how it goes.